# How do the various LevelDB-like key-value stores compare?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, okvs

Out of LevelDB, RocksDB, HyperLevelDB, LMDB, and any others that fit in this category, what are the expected performance properties and tradeoffs between them?

I've found various benchmarks and articles making claims regarding parts of what I'm looking for, but none that are very recent, so it's unclear how much of the information is still accurate/relevant. e.g. I'm seeing that the latter three may be better than Level in terms of things like concurrency and read performance, but I'm not sure how much of that is true or how they would compare to each other either way.

Comment: You can't merely compare performance, you first need to figure what are your functional requirements.